# graded Betti number with non honogeneous generator

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

In calculating the minimal resolution of the homogeneous ideal $I=\langle x^2,y^2,xy+yz \rangle$ I find the following minimal presentation:
$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
0 @<<< R/I @<<< R @<\left(\begin{array}{ccc}yz^2&y^2&xy+yz  \end{array} \right)<< R^3
  @<\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0&y^2&xy+yz\\-x-z&-z^2&0\\y&-xy+yz&-x^2 \end{array}\right)<< R^3
  @<\left(\begin{array}{c} z^2\\-x-z\\y \end{array}\right)<< R
  @<<< 0
\end{CD}$$
The first $R$ is $R(0)$. The second free module is $R(-3)\oplus R(-2)\oplus R(-2)$ from the degree of $yz^2$, $y^2$ and $xy+yz$.

For the third free module I have a problem:

- The first column is $\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\-x-z\\y \end{array}\right)$ which is a homogeneous vector of degree 3 because:
  $$ \deg((-x-z)e_2)=1+\deg(e_2)=1+2=3\text{ and }\deg(ye_3)=1+\deg(e_3)=1+2=3 $$
  As a result the first summand of the third free module will be $R(-3)$.
- The second and third vector **are not homogeneous**. For example the vector $\left(\begin{array}{c}y^2\\-z^2\\-xy+yz \end{array}\right)$:
  $$ \deg(y^2e_1)=2+\deg(e_1)=2+3=5\text{ but }\deg(-z^2e_2)=2+\deg(e_2)=2+2=4 $$

So my question is: how can we get the graded betty number from a minimal resolution when the column of morphisms are not homogeneous?

I could make a resolution not minimal but with homogeneous columns for example by making two columns from the column $\left(\begin{array}{c}y^2\\-z^2\\-xy+yz \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\-z^2\\-xy+yz \end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c}y^2\\0\\0 \end{array}\right)$. But it's no more minimal...

Comment: Where does the $yz^2$ come from? The ideal you wish to resolve is $I=(x^2,y^2,xy+yz)$ correct?

Comment: It comes from the minimalization of a free resolution that I calculated with Schreyer method i.e. using the relations coming from Burchberger algorithm: a Groebner basis of $\langle x^2,y^2,xy+yz \rangle$ is $\{x^2,y^2,xy+yz,yz^2\}$.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand what you are trying to do. The sequence you have provided is not even a complex, since the image of the second map is the ideal $(yz^2,y^2,xy+yz)$ which is not contained in $I$. Is this intentional?

Comment: You are right, there is a problem with my resolution: the compositions of map is not null. For minimize the resolution I used a software (Singular) and it seems there is a problem here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In fact I think the resolution gives always homogeneous vectors: it comes from the nullity of composition of successive maps.